# Reading Custom Document properties in MS Word File using python

Tags: python-2.7, ms-word, pywin32

How can I get the document properties of a MS-Word 2010 Document using python?

with document properties i mean those who can be added or modified under FILE -> Info-> Properties-> Advanced properties (In MS-WORD 2010)

I'm using python 2.7 on windows764bit and the corresponding pywin32com version to access the doc-file...

I found the  **CustomProperty**-object with the methods **value** and **name** witch seem to be the right thing for my purpose (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257518%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

But I dont know how to implement the class members in python...

the thing i want to do is to get manually specified properties like author, version...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it by myself...

A way to read the custom document properties is:

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
word.Visible = 0
doc = word.Documents.Open(file)
try:
    csp= doc.CustomDocumentProperties('property_you_want_to_know').value
    print('property is %s' % csp)

except exception as e:
    print ('\n\n', e)

doc.Saved= False
doc.Save()
doc.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. it helped me. minor change, i think it should : "doc = word.Documents.Open(file)"  and following line gave me error while running so i commented                                         
doc.Saved= False
doc.Save()
doc.Close()

Answer (score 1):

For later Word documents (docx) also module `python-docx` can be used for reading or setting of document properties:

```
from docx import Document

path = 'D:/myfile.docx'
# create document handler
document = Document(path)
# read properties
document_property = document.core_properties
# print all accessible document properties
print([p for p in dir(document_property) if not p.startswith('_')])
# print author of the document
print(document_property.author)
# set new value for title
document_property.title = 'Everything is Awesome'
# save changes to current file
document.save(path)
```

Comment: Sorry -1 as the question is about custom properties, not core properties. Docx unfortunately does not support custom properties yet.